# Scrape table through iteration only after data loads with delay using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data using python (Requests and BeautifulSoup4 libraries along with Selenium)

When I tried to get some data out of website where the data loads after some delay, it returns an empty value. I understand that for this task i have to use WebDriverWait.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# selenium imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# Initialize a Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Grab the web page
driver.get("http://")

# use selenium.webdriver.support.ui.Select
# that we imported above to grab the Select element called 
# lmStatType, then select the first value

# We will use .find_element_by_name here because we know the name
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("lmStatType"))
dropdown.select_by_value("1")

# select the year 2560
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("lmYear"))
dropdown.select_by_value("60")

# Now we can grab the search button and click it
search_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'ตกลง')]"[0]
search_button.click()

# we just look at .page_source of the driver
driver.page_source

# We can feed that into Beautiful Soup
doc = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

# It's a tricky table, also tried with class names
rows = doc.find('table', id='datatable')
print(rows) # returns empty
```

In the above example i haven't used the tried options with selenium webdriver wait  & timeout related statements for understanding it step-by-step, even though i have tried several workarounds.

Also, just tried grabbing the district level data separately like (but can't figure out the exact class/id)

```
url = 'http://'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for tr in soup.find(class_="display").find_all("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tr.find_all(["th","td"])]
    print(data)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance. My apology, if this is a duplicate question.

Comment: If you could get the data directly from /datasource/showStatProvince.php?statType=1&year=60" 
 - that would probably be a lot easier...

Comment: Cannot get data directly from the url as the processing is via js function

Comment: sure you can. The javascript-funktion in your HTML actually gives you the right url to fetch the data directly. That endpoint returns json...

Comment: Unfortunately once you post you can't remove. You'll have to request dissociation using the contact us link at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in a comment the html actually gives you the endpoint where it gets that data. From the on it's actually quite easy getting the data using requests.

In your html as reads: "sAjaxSource": "../datasource/showStatProvince.php?statType=1&year=60". This is the endpoint the site uses. So you just need to go one level back in the sites url-structure and use "/datasource/...." instead

Take look:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "http://stat.bora.dopa.go.th/stat/statnew/statTDD/datasource/showStatDistrict.php?statType=1&year=60&rcode=10"

r = requests.get(url)
# endpoint returns json
data = r.json()
aaData = data['aaData']

# this base url for viewing the details for each hit
view_url = "http://stat.bora.dopa.go.th/stat/statnew/statTDD/views/showZoneData.php"

# the first line in the dataset is actually html
# we convert this to plain text
html_header = aaData[0]
html_header_stripped = [BeautifulSoup(e, "html.parser").get_text() for e in html_header]

# and the insert this html_header_stripped in the aaData-list
aaData[0] = html_header_stripped
for rcode, region_html,male,female, total, home in aaData:
    # first element is "<font color='red'><b>กรุงเทพมหานคร</b></font>"
    # secound is "<a href=javascript:openWindow('?rcode=1001&statType=1&year=60')>ท้องถิ่นเขตพระนคร</a>"
    # we need to extract the link that opens in new window to be able to iterate further
    soup = BeautifulSoup(region_html, "html.parser")
    region = soup.get_text()
    try:
        link_element = soup.find('a').get('href')
        rel_link = re.search("\('(.+)'\)", link_element).group(1)
        abs_link = view_url + rel_link
    except:
        abs_link = None

    print("{};{};{};{};{};{};{}".format(rcode, region, abs_link,male,female,total,home))
```

Here I'm printing the results, but say you wanted to follow the links and grab that data, you could store the results in a list of dicts and iterate over this subsequently or do it inside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Infact then there was no need to even use selenium.

Comment: Nope. If it solves your problem please accept the qnswer. Selenium should imho be your absolutely last resort when all reverse engineering fails...

Comment: Why did you remove the accept of the answer again? If you want to ask another question regarding how lists and dictionaries work in Python please do so, but those are entirely other questions. SO is not a 'please write me a scraper'-central. I'll gladly do so for you. I charge $200 an hour as a developer.

Comment: The answer you provided does help, but i am looking for end-to-end automation. Never worked on dynamic responsive scraping before. Sorry jlaur

Comment: Shouldn't be. Put it in a list and loop through it. I've shown you how to scrape one. Just loop it with a for loop...

Comment: And of course if the subpages have different structures/endpoints etc, you need to figure out how to scrape that as well. You should consider first tho how to store thata data. What exactly would be your final output pr line when you reach the 4th level. A flat file? Tables for mysql/sqlite? Dicts to elasticsearch? Thats probably where you should start before coding at all.

Comment: Okay. At first i want to store it as a flat file. Then, later i may think for tables for sql

Comment: Then ask yourself EXACTLY which fields would you want line by line. Write them down. Which fields are from which level. Once you're done build a scraper for each level. Once that works put the pieces together.

Comment: Yes will follow the same procedure as mentioned

Comment: @Ach - you seem to try to redact my answer so the website-url and other site specific stuff is deleted from SO. What's that about?

Comment: Hi jlaur. I had by mistakenly posted the actual website-url as example, but i was not supposed to have done that due to data privacy issues being the govt agency.

Comment: How could it ever be a problem linking to an  uncontroversial public database online?

Comment: Hi jlaur. Things are very weird here. Issue is made out of nothing.